# Pass column index and range simultaneously in Pandas iloc

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Suppose I have a dataframe with 100 columns. I want to select only 0,1 and 51-100 columns for all rows. I am trying something like this as of now:

```
df.iloc[:,[0,1,range(51,101)]]
```

But it is throwing error:

**"setting an array element with a sequence"**

Though it is working if I am passing only range and not column indices.

Also I have tried:

```
df.iloc[:,[0,1,51:102)]]
```

It is showing invalid syntax.

Can somebody please point out mistake here. Also please suggest alternative way to achieve functionality.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you need [`numpy.r_`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.r_.html) for concanecate indices:

```
df.iloc[:,np.r_[0,1,51:102]]
```

Sample:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[0] * 10], columns=list('abcdefghij'))
print (df)
   a  b  c  d  e  f  g  h  i  j
0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0

print (df.iloc[:,np.r_[0,1,5:8]])
   a  b  f  g  h
0  0  0  0  0  0
```

Answer (score 4):

You can do this without `numpy.r_`:

```py
new_df = df.iloc[:, [0, 1] + list(range(51,101))]
```

Comment: This is a much neater solution, thanks!