# Selecting columns in Pandas dataframe based on Condition

Tags: python, pandas

I have an Excel sheet where columns are like this:

[image: ![Day 1]

Now the next day it can change like this

[image: Day 2]

So every time I have to select Name column and then after Class and just before Porting.
So in between one day it can have 2 column and another day it can have 4 column.

Any idea how to achieve this.

Answer (score 2):

If need select all columns between `Class` and `Porting` include this columns:

```
df.loc[:, 'Class':'Porting']
```

If need exclude columns `Class` and `Porting`:

```
df.iloc[:, df.columns.get_loc('Class')+1:df.columns.get_loc('Porting')]
```

For include first column you can use [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44794759/2901002):

```
df.iloc[:, np.r_[0, df.columns.get_loc('Class')+1:df.columns.get_loc('Porting')]]
```

Comment: Hi @jezrael, i have modified the question. can you check please. i need to always add first column as well.

Comment: @AnupamKumar - Is possible convert first columkn to index? like `df = df.set_index(1)`, then use my solution and last `df = df.reset_index()` ?

Comment: @jezreal. I did this. but the 2nd df is not having Name column than.

df.set_index('Name')

df.iloc[:,df.columns.get_loc('Class')+1:df.columns.get_loc('Porting')]

Answer (score 0):

column_to_select = ['Name','Age','Sim','Salary','Address']  ## make a variable list of columns to be selected ##

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns_to_select)## while reading data pass the column list to select ##